# Negamax for turn based game

Tags: ai, turn-based

I am working on a fast paced turn based game, each turn the player can move left, right or stay put and choose whether or not to fire. Each turn the shots move one block in the direction they are pointing.

I would like to implement NegaMax on this game for curiosity's sake.

Could anyone recommend a brilliant tutorial they tried and found satisfactory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Hamed's tutorial](http://www.hamedahmadi.com/gametree/) the best one from all the links I've read. Also, look at [chessprogramming](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Negamax).